# Apple Rejection Policy and Programming Guide versioning

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Is there any sort of change control documentation available regarding Apple's Programming Guidelines and rejections policies?

In the last few months our apps have been getting rejected for code that hasn't changed since the previous version.  The two recent issues are Dropbox and now the in-app restore button.  When you have to wait 12 days+, I would like a greater degree of certainty releases wont be rejected.

Comment: As far as I know, Dropbox was indeed an issue but was resolved by Dropbox's new sdk. In-app-restore is a requirement being enhanced by Apple in these two months. This does improve the user experience though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are Apple guidelines,

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

Bare in mind that if apple wants to be stubborn with some things, they will find a way to make you change what they want. Dropbox problem was resolved, and IAP restore button is mandatory though.

Comment: Thanks tomi,  The information I'm looking for is what breaches Apple have started enforcing so prior to releasing an update, I can resolve these issues before uploading.

Comment: I think the best way to know about changes in Apple guideline enforcements is to monitor Twitter and other developer channels. It would be nice if Apple notified us when the decide to enforce something, but they don't usually.